# How to define a Deref trait bound that allows any number of Deref::deref calls

Tags: generics, rust

I have a `Rc<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` and I want to write a function that expects a type that can be dereferenced into `&MyTrait`.

Below is what I tried and the error I received. Can this be achieved in Rust?

```
use std::rc::Rc;
use std::ops::Deref;

trait MyTrait {
    
}

struct Foo {
}

impl MyTrait for Foo {
    
}

fn bar<T : Deref<Target = dyn MyTrait>>(obj: &T) {
    
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(Box::new(Foo {}) as Box<dyn MyTrait>);
    bar(&foo)
}
```

And this is the error I'm getting:

```
  Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<Rc<Box<dyn MyTrait>> as Deref>::Target == dyn MyTrait`
  --> src/main.rs:21:9
   |
21 |     bar(&foo)
   |     --- ^^^^ expected `dyn MyTrait`, found `Box<dyn MyTrait>`
   |     |
   |     required by a bound introduced by this call
   |
   = note: expected trait object `(dyn MyTrait + 'static)`
                    found struct `Box<dyn MyTrait>`
note: required by a bound in `bar`
  --> src/main.rs:15:18
   |
15 | fn bar<T : Deref<Target = dyn MyTrait>>(obj: &T) {
   |                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `bar`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0271`.
error: could not compile `playground` (bin "playground") due to 1 previous error
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to write a trait *bound* that does this kind of recursion. (And in part because of that, `Deref` trait bounds are not often useful.) However, you can implement *a specific trait* recursively, that is, this compiles:

```rust
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::rc::Rc;

trait MyTrait {}

struct Foo {}
impl MyTrait for Foo {}

impl<T: ?Sized> MyTrait for T
where
    T: Deref,
    T::Target: MyTrait,
{
    // delegate operations to `*self`
}

fn bar<T: MyTrait>(obj: &T) {}

fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(Box::new(Foo {}) as Box<dyn MyTrait>);
    bar(&foo)
}
```

The implementations of the trait `MyTrait` serves to define the two cases of the recursive operation: every implementor of `MyTrait` is either a `Foo` or dereferences to another implementor.

It's more common, though, to write recursive implementations like this not in terms of `Deref` but on specific pointer types (`&T`, `&mut T`, `Box<T>`...) This is because avoiding writing a *blanket implementation* (`impl<T...> MyTrait for T`) gives more room for other implementors of the trait.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple things you have got wrong. First don't write a function that takes `&T` as an argument where `T: Deref<Target = Foo>` when really all you want is `&Foo`. Just take `&Foo` and let [Deref coercion](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html#deref-coercion) do it's job. For example in your case.

```rust
use std::rc::Rc;

trait MyTrait {}

struct Foo;

impl MyTrait for Foo {}

fn bar(obj: &dyn MyTrait) {
    todo!()
}

fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(Box::new(Foo) as Box<dyn MyTrait>);
    bar(&**foo)
}
```

And second `Rc<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` is odd. You can just use `Rc<dyn MyTrait>` instead:

```rust
fn main() {
    let foo = Rc::new(Foo) as Rc<dyn MyTrait>;
    bar(&*foo)
}
```

Comment: Deref coercion doesn't work here because it tries to turn `Rc<Box<dyn MyTrait>>` into `dyn MyTrait`. It's generally not going to work with generics or trait objects. I think this kind of coercion only works for method calls.